# Input from one file and match it in other and print until a pattern match

Tags: sed, xargs

I am having two files. `File1` contain the following IDs:

```
id/35651
id/35325
id/20993
id/30167
id/29807
id/28315
id/29759
id/27715
id/26884
id/30412
```

`File2` contains multiple IDs, similar pattern like `File1`, followed by multiline description. Now, I want to print all the IDs with description from `File2` which are present in `File1`.
File2 is huge. I am having a smaller version here

```
>id/30412
GCACACATTTTCTCGCGCTCTCTCCGGCTCTCCTTTGTTTATTTTCTAATCTATATTTTTACTGGAAGAT
TTCCTCTTTATTCTCTCCCGCCCTCCTACAAGCGCTCTTGCTGGCCGTCTGGGTGCACACACCGCTCCCT
CGATCACCCCAGCCCCCTTCCTGGTCTCCCGAGCGCGGGGTTTGAAGGTCACCTCCTTTCCAGTCCCCGT
GCGAGCCGCGCTGCCGCCGCCTCCTCCAGCCAGAGTCGGTGGGACTGGCTGCGCTGCCCTGAAGTGGTTC
TCCAAGCAGCGCGGAGGGTGGCGGACGGCGGACGGAGCCCAGGGGCCGCGTCGGGTGGGGAAACCCGAAC
>id/28315
TCGCGGAGGGGAATCCCTCCCCCTCCGCCCCAGCCCCCCAGCAGCACCCGCGGTGGGGCGGGGGCGCTCT
GCCAGCCCCGGGAACAGCAGAGGCGGCGGCACTGGCTGGACCCACGCGCGCGCCTCCGGGGCTGAAGAAG
GAAGGAGTGAGCCGAGCCGAGCACCCCACATCTGGAGGGGACAGCCAGCCGTGGGCCCCGCCCCGGCGTC
CGGAGCAGGAGAACTCCGAGCTTCTTGCCCAGGCAGAGAGAGCAGGAGCGGACCGCGCGCCCGGGATTGA
>id/2313
GAGTCCTTGCGCTCCAGACCCCCACCCAGTGGCCGCCAGGGTCCCCGCCTGTCCGGACCCTCGCCGCGCC
CAGGCAGGCGCGCCAGGGCGGGGCTGACCTGCCCGCGAAGTTGCGGACAGTGCGTGAGAAACCAGCACCC
CCTTTATGGAAACTGGTCAAAGAACTCATGCAAGTGGAACTTACAGCTTCCTTGATCGGACTCAGCATTC
AGGGCCCAGTTTGCTCCCCCGCAGAACGGTATCCCCGCGGAATACACGGCCCCTCATCCCCACCCCGCGC
CAGAGTACACAGGCCAGACCACGGTTCCCGAGCACACATTAAACCTGTACCCTCCCGCCCAGACGCACTC
>id/26884
CGAGCAGAGCCCGGCGGACACGAGCGCTCAGACCGTCTCTGGCACCGCCACACAGACAGATGACGCAGCA
CCGACGGATGGCCAGCCCCAGACACAACCTTCTGAAAACACGGAAAACAAGTCTCAGCCCAAGCGGCTGC
ATGTCTCCAATATCCCCTTCAGGTTCCGGGATCCGGACCTCAGACAAATGTTTGGTCAATTTGGTAAAAT
CTTAGATGTTGAAATTATTTTTAATGAGCGAGGCTCAAAGGGATTTGGTTTCGTAACTTTCGAAAATAGT
>id/29807
GCCGATGCGGACAGGGCGAGGGAGAAATTACACGGCACCGTGGTAGAGGGCCGTAAAATCGAGGTAAATA
ATGCCACAGCACGTGTAATGACAAATAAAAAGACCGTCAACCCTTATACAAATGGCTGGAAATTGAATCC
AGTTGTGGGTGCAGTCTACAGTCCCGAATTCTATGCAGCACGGTCCTGTTGTGCCAGGCCAACCAGGAGG
GATCTTCCATGTACAGTGCCCCCAGTTCACTTGTATATACTTCTGCAATGCCAGGCTTCCCGTATCCAGC
AGCCACCGCCGCGGCCGCCTACCGAGGGGCGCACCTGCGAGGCCGCGGTCGCACCGTGTACAACACCTTC
>id/980
AGGGCCGCGGCGCCCCCGCCCCCGATCCCGGCCTACGGCGGTGTTGTTTACCAGGATGGATTTTATGGTG
CAGACATTTATGGTGGTTATGCTGCATACCGCTACGCCCAGCCTACCCCTGCCACTGCCGCTGCCTACAG
TGACAGTTACGGACGAGTTTATGCTGCCGACCCCTACCACCACGCACTTGCTCCAGCCCCCACCTACGGC
GTTGGTGCCATGAATGCTTTTGCACCTTTGACTGATGCCAAGACTAGGAGCCATGCTGATGATGTGGGTC
TCGTTCTTTCTTCATTGCAGGCTAGTATATACCGAGGGGGATACAACCGTTTTGCTCCATACTAAATGAC
AAAACCATAAAAACCTTCCAATGTGGGGAGAAAGGAAGCTTTCCGAGGCCTGAGTATTGCAATACATGCA
GTAGTACATCATTTTAGCAACTCT
```

I can do it one by one with the following command:

```
sed -n -e '/id\/30412/,/id/p' File2
```

But I am not sure how to tell sed to get the input from `File1`.

Also, is it possible not to print the matching pattern `id\number` in the last line?

Comment: You have to show example contents of `File2` as well.

Comment: @oguzismail: Not obliged for sed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's|id/\(.*\)|\\#^>id/\1$#{:\1;n;/^>/ba;b\1}|' file1 |
sed -e ':a' -f - -e 'd' file2
```

Build a sed script from file1 and run it against file2.

For each id build a loop which prints the current line then fetches the next line (`n`) and then checks if that line begins with `<`. If it does the script breaks to `:a` and checks for a new id, otherwise it prints the current lines and loops to a unique place holder based on the current id and continues printing.

Lines that do not match any id are deleted (`d`).

Comment: if file1 contail id/356 and file2 contail id/356, id/3568, id/35601; it capturing all three. How to restrict it to only perfect match?

Comment: @user3377241 just add `$` to the end of the generated id address. See edit.